# What is the optimal strategy for increasing my 'mathematical maturity'? Depth or breadth? Number theory or measure theory?

Tags: soft-question

My apologies for such a general question, but as a 'math enthusiast', I've often wondered what the optimal strategy is to increase my mathematical maturity. Broadly, should I aim to hunker down & study one topic in detail (measure theory/analysis, which is what i'm doing right now), or should I study a broad swathe of different topics?

Also, are there specific fields of math that are better for developing mathematical maturity? I've often wondered whether number theory/graph theory/combinatorics are better for developing mathematical maturity as even basic proofs need one to think imaginatively.

My apologies again for such a broad question that will likely have many different contradicting responses. However, I don't have anyone to discuss this with, so thought I'd throw out my question here.

Comment: Can you give us a better idea of where you are as a mathematician? We could probably give a better next step with this information.

Comment: Write proofs. Get feedback on them.

Comment: I know a good bit of point-set topology (Munkres), some algebra (Herstein). Really enjoyed Baby Rudin. Currently trying to learn measure theory. I've enjoyed combinatorics/graph theory/number theory but don't really know too much other than the basics there.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Try to teach what you learned (also what you want to learn) to people with different background!